# How do I input this Boolean Expression into a K map?

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

Determine the minimum SOP, sum of products expression using K-Map

F(A,B,C,D,E) = (A’ + B + C’ + D + E’)(A’ + C’ +  D + E )(A’ + C’ +  E )AC’

Do i have to actually simplify it first by multiplying AC' with (A'+C'+E) ? since id assume AC' is in SoP and the rest are in PoS form?... I am stuck at the moment. I do know how to complete after when I have everything in the same form. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Last term is not Sum of Products.  Take DeMorgans on it. (A' + C)

Now you have SOP.  For each term, invert terms A' = 1, or A = 0 and put 0's in for your modified terms.  (A' + C) means all terms with A = 1 and C = 0 will be 0 (8 terms).

1st term will have 1 zero, 2nd = 2, 3rd = 4, Last = 8.

Circle 1's.  Generate equation.

F(A,B,C,D,E) = A' + BCE + CDE